# Control-M: SMART Folder - get information of inside job

Tags: control-m

I use SMART Folder to get email notifications if jobs inside that folder changed their status to failed.

When an email notification is sent I need to get the name of the failing job inside the SMART folder.

Is there a way to get information about failed jobs inside SMART folder via some variables?
I tried  `%%SCHEDTAB` and `%%JOBNAME` but this only relates to the SMART folder and not the failing job inside.

[On Do Action in SMART folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQfTy.png)

[Monitoring view example of SMART table with failed job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/678Uq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the alert to go from individual jobs instead. I often just have a standardised post-proc panel for the job that generates an alert using local variables, e.g. -

%%JOBNAME failed on %%NODEID with code = %%COMPSTAT.. This is a %%APPLGROUP job running on the %%APPLIC system.